Creating a git monorepo from two diverging branches of the same repository
I'm working with a git repository which contains two diverging branches which are both deployed to our production environment in separate, adjacent folders. I'd like to create a new git repository replicating this production folder setup, such that the contents of both branches exist in folders in the main branch.
I need the final folder structure to look like the following:
git/branch-one # All files from branch-one in this folder
git/branch-two # All files from branch-two in this folder

My attempts thus far have involved the following:

Branching off branch-one and git mv-ing everything into a git/branch-one folder
Branching off branch-two and git mv-ing everything into a git/branch-two folder
Creating a brand new repository, adding the existing repository as a remote.
Git merging the existing repositories branches using --allow-unrelated-histories:

git merge -m "Integrating branch one into monorepo" existing-repo/branch-one-monorepo --allow-unrelated-histories
git merge -m "Integrating branch two into monorepo" existing-repo/branch-two-monorepo --allow-unrelated-histories

It's at this point I get a series of merge conflicts, which is to be expected since there is a significant overlap from the early stages of these branches.
Is there any way to resolve these conflicts automatically? Ultimately I'd like the history to be as complete as possible, but I'm not against having duplicate items in the history for each version of the files that now exists if that is possible. As I'm new to this codebase, going through the conflicts manually is something I'm keen to avoid.

¿Are you aware that you can get content from different branches in different folders from the original repo without creating a new monorepo?

@user7860670 I have more repositories I need to merge into my monorepo which don't have the same problems as the repository in question (ie. no diverging branches). I left them out of the question as I wasn't convinced they were relevant. That said, I'm not against a solution which effectively makes this repository the monorepo, so long as I have the desired final folder structure in one branch.

Are you perhaps totally misunderstanding the purpose of branches in relation to folders/directories?

@j6t Indeed, I am trying to unravel the codebase from this situation. It's a scenario I've inherited. It appears that a rewrite of this module was attempted, but then for some reason it was decided that both the rewrite and the old code should continue to be used in production, and they have both been worked on in two separate branches - effectively having two main branches. I want to put an end to this madness :)

To create a combined-checkout setup like this you can use added worktrees, and track them with a usage the git submodule helper isn't really expecting but Git can handle just fine and the helper can be noodged into handling cleanly.
Step 1: create a new ~production checkouts~ branch that will track what was checked out and where from multiple branches. This is already good enough for the experienced to work with, everything else is just taking notes for convenience commands.
git checkout --orphan -b production-checkouts-tracker
git rm -rfq .
git worktree add git/branch-one branch-one   # production uses these two branches in parallel
git worktree add git/branch-two branch-two   # ... so make a branch that tracks the specifics

and you've got the existing branches checked out where you want them. You could manage all this without the submodule helper, by just adding the checkouts with git add . and maybe shutting off the advisory warnings, but longterm the easier way is probably
Step 2: tell the submodule helper what's going on:
# continuing in the checkout set up above
>.gitmodules
git submodule add --name branch-one ./git/branch-one git/branch-one
git submodule add --name branch-two ./git/branch-two git/branch-two
git submodule set-url git/branch-one .
git submodule set-url git/branch-two .

and now your repo's set up properly, when you want to replicate this in a freshly cloned repo
Step 3: check out the tracker branch, git checkout production-checkouts-tracker, and either
GIT_ALLOW_PROTOCOL=file git submodule update --init

or do what that winds up doing
git submodule init
git worktree add git/branch-one :git/branch-one
git worktree add git/branch-two :git/branch-two


One of the solutions is to use 2 plumbing commands:

git mktree
git commit-tree

Create a tree that represents everything under the directory git/.
# "branch-one" and "branch-two" mean the real names of the branches
# make sure that branch-one and branch-two have been updated to the right commits
# you can replace them with the specific commit sha1 values
branch1tree=$(git rev-parse branch-one^{tree})
branch2tree=$(git rev-parse branch-two^{tree})

# "branch-one" and "branch-two" after \t mean the real names of the folders
gittree=$(echo -e "040000 tree ${branch1tree}\tbranch-one\n040000 tree ${branch2tree}\tbranch-two" | git mktree)

Create a root tree that represents the parent directory of git/.
# "git" following \t means the real name of the folder
roottree=$(echo -e "040000 tree ${gittree}\tgit" | git mktree)

Create a new commit from this root tree as if the commit merges branch-one and branch-two, resulting in a new directory structure. It does not involve any merge conflicts.
# "branch-one" and "branch-two" following `-p` mean the real names of the branches
newhead=$(git commit-tree -p branch-one -p branch-two -m "merge branch-one and branch-two, and create a new directory structure" ${roottree})

Create a local branch foo from newhead.
git branch foo ${newhead}

Check the history of foo.
git log --oneline --graph --decorate foo

You can push foo to the new remote repository and create a main branch.
git push ${url_to_new_repo} foo:main

